# If else statement not showing proper output in Flutter

Tags: android, database, flutter, dart, if-statement

I am following a course video from YouTube to design a shopping cart in Flutter. But according to the course video, I am supposed to see the output showing the pictures of the items, their prices, units, and other details [shown in picture 1]. But in my output I am seeing nothing but only the AppBar title [shown in picture 2].

`The output in the YouTube course video:`

[image: Sample]

`My Output:`

[image: My Output]

I have attached the entire code below, please help fix my mistake.

`main.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shopping_cart/cart_provider.dart';
import 'package:shopping_cart/cart_screen.dart';
import 'package:shopping_cart/product_list.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => CartProvider(),
      child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: const CartScreen(),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

`product_list.dart`

```
import 'package:badges/badges.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide Badge;
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shopping_cart/cart_model.dart';
import 'package:shopping_cart/db_helper.dart';
import 'cart_provider.dart';
import 'cart_screen.dart';

class ProductListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProductListScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<ProductListScreen> createState() => _ProductListScreenState();
}

class _ProductListScreenState extends State<ProductListScreen> {
  DBHelper? dbHelper = DBHelper();

  List<String> productName = [
    'Mango',
    'Orange',
    'Grapes',
    'Banana',
    'Chery',
    'Peach',
    'Mixed Fruit Basket'
  ];
  List<String> productUnit = [
    'KG',
    'Dozen',
    'KG',
    'Dozen',
    'KG',
    'KG',
    'KG',
  ];
  List<int> productPrice = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70];
  List<String> productImage = [
    'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mango-isolated-on-white-background-600w-610892249.jpg',
    'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/orange-fruit-slices-leaves-isolated-600w-1386912362.jpg',
    'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/green-grape-leaves-isolated-on-600w-533487490.jpg',
    'https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/banana-picture-id1184345169?s=612x612',
    'https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/cherry-trio-with-stem-and-leaf-picture-id157428769?s=612x612',
    'https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/single-whole-peach-fruit-with-leaf-and-slice-isolated-on-white-picture-id1151868959?s=612x612',
    'https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/fruit-background-picture-id529664572?s=612x612',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cart = Provider.of<CartProvider>(context); // reference
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Product List"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        actions: [
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => CartScreen(),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Center(
              child: Badge(
                badgeContent: Consumer<CartProvider>(
                  builder: (context, value, child) {
                    return Text(
                      value.getCounter().toString(),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                badgeAnimation: const BadgeAnimation.fade(
                  animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                ),
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.shopping_cart_outlined,
                  size: 30,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 20),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: productName.length,
              itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                return Card(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          children: [
                            Image(
                              height: 100,
                              width: 100,
                              image:
                                  NetworkImage(productImage[index].toString()),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              width: 15,
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    productName[index],
                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 23),
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    height: 5,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    productUnit[index] +
                                        " " r"$" +
                                        productPrice[index].toString(),
                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 23),
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    height: 10,
                                  ),
                                  Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                    child: InkWell(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        dbHelper!
                                            .insert(Cart(
                                                id: index,
                                                productId: index.toString(),
                                                productName: productName[index]
                                                    .toString(),
                                                initialPrice:
                                                    productPrice[index],
                                                productPrice:
                                                    productPrice[index],
                                                quantity: 1,
                                                unitTag: productUnit[index]
                                                    .toString(),
                                                image: productImage[index]
                                                    .toString()))
                                            .then((value) {
                                          print("Product is Added to Cart");
                                          cart.addTotalPrice(double.parse(
                                              productPrice[index].toString()));
                                          cart.addCounter();
                                        }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
                                          print(error.toString());
                                        });
                                      },
                                      child: Container(
                                        height: 35,
                                        width: 130,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                          color: Colors.green,
                                        ),
                                        child: const Center(
                                          child: Text(
                                            "Add to Cart",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                fontSize: 20,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
            ),
          ),
          Consumer<CartProvider>(builder: (context, value, child) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                ReusableWidget(
                  'subtotal',
                  r'$' + value.getTotalPrice().toStringAsFixed(2),
                ),
              ],
            );
          })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ReusableWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title, value;
  const ReusableWidget(this.title, this.value, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Text(
            title,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleSmall,
          ),
          Text(
            value,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleSmall,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`db_helper.dart`

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'cart_model.dart';

class DBHelper {
  static Database? _db;

  Future<Database?> get db async {
    _db = await initDatabase();
    if (_db != null) {
      return _db!;
    }
  }

  initDatabase() async {
    io.Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentDirectory.path, 'cart.db');
    var db = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return db;
  }

  // Method
  _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(
      'CREATE TABLE cart (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, productId VARCHAR UNIQUE, productName TEXT, initialPrice INTEGER, productPrice INTEGER, quantity INTEGER, unitTag TEXT, image TEXT)',
    );
  }

  Future<Cart> insert(Cart cart) async {
    print(cart.toMap());
    var dbClient = await db;
    await dbClient!.insert('cart', cart.toMap());
    return cart;
  }

  Future<List<Cart>> getCartList() async {
    var dbClient = await db;

    final List<Map<String, Object?>> queryResult =
        await dbClient!.query("cart");

    return queryResult.map((e) => Cart.fromMap(e)).toList();
  }
}
```

`cart_screen.dart`

```
import 'package:badges/badges.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide Badge;
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'cart_model.dart';
import 'cart_provider.dart';

class CartScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CartScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<CartScreen> createState() => _CartScreenState();
}

class _CartScreenState extends State<CartScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cart = Provider.of<CartProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("My Products"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        actions: [
          Center(
            child: Badge(
              badgeContent: Consumer<CartProvider>(
                builder: (context, value, child) {
                  return Text(
                    value.getCounter().toString(),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              badgeAnimation: const BadgeAnimation.fade(
                animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              ),
              child: const Icon(
                Icons.shopping_cart_outlined,
                size: 30,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 20),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          FutureBuilder(
            future: cart.getData(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Cart>> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                      return Card(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                children: [
                                  Image(
                                    height: 100,
                                    width: 100,
                                    image: NetworkImage(
                                      snapshot.data![index].image.toString(),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    width: 15,
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          snapshot.data![index].productName
                                              .toString(),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(
                                          height: 5,
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          snapshot.data![index].unitTag
                                                  .toString() +
                                              " " r"$" +
                                              snapshot.data![index].productPrice
                                                  .toString(),
                                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 23),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(
                                          height: 10,
                                        ),
                                        Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                          child: InkWell(
                                            onTap: () {},
                                            child: Container(
                                              height: 35,
                                              width: 130,
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                                color: Colors.green,
                                              ),
                                              child: const Center(
                                                child: Text(
                                                  "Add to Cart",
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                      fontSize: 20,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.w500),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return const Text("Shahzain");
              }
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`cart_provider.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:shopping_cart/cart_model.dart';
import 'package:shopping_cart/db_helper.dart';

class CartProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  DBHelper db = DBHelper(); // DBHelper() is a class
  int _counter = 0;
  int get counter => _counter;

  double _totalPrice = 0.0;
  double get totalPrice => _totalPrice;

  late Future<List<Cart>> _cart;
  Future<List<Cart>> get cart => _cart; // => means to indicate

  Future<List<Cart>> getData() async {
    _cart = db.getCartList();
    return _cart;
  }

  void _setPrefItems() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setInt('cart_item', _counter);
    prefs.setDouble('total_price', _totalPrice);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void _getPrefItems() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    // giving initial value by ?? 0 for null safety
    _counter = prefs.getInt('cart_item') ?? 0;

    // giving initial value by ?? 0.0 for null safety
    _totalPrice = prefs.getDouble('total_price') ?? 0.0;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void addTotalPrice(double productPrice) {
    _totalPrice = _totalPrice + productPrice;
    _setPrefItems();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeTotalPrice(double productPrice) {
    _totalPrice = _totalPrice - productPrice;
    _setPrefItems();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  double getTotalPrice() {
    _getPrefItems();
    return _totalPrice;
  }

  void addCounter() {
    // initial value of counter was 0, will be incremented to 1, and will be stored to sharedPreferences
    _counter++;
    _setPrefItems();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeCounter() {
    _counter--;
    _setPrefItems();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int getCounter() {
    _getPrefItems();
    return _counter;
  }
}
```

`cart_model.dart`

```
class Cart {
  late final int? id;
  final String? productId;
  final String? productName;
  final int? initialPrice;
  final int? productPrice;
  final int? quantity;
  final String? unitTag;
  final String? image;


// Creating the constructor
Cart({
  required this.id, // primary key
  required this.productId,
  required this.productName,
  required this.initialPrice,
  required this.productPrice, 
  required this.quantity,
  required this.unitTag,
  required this.image,
});

Cart.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> res) // res = resources
: id = res['id'], 
productId = res['productId'],
productName = res['productName'],
initialPrice = res['initialPrice'],
productPrice = res['productPrice'],
quantity = res['quantity'],
unitTag = res['unitTag'],
image = res['image'];

Map<String, Object?> toMap(){
  return  {
    'id' : id,
    'productId' : productId,
    'productName' : productName,
    'initialPrice' : initialPrice,
    'productPrice' : productPrice,
    'quantity' : quantity,
    'unitTag' : unitTag,
    'image' : image
  };
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `main.dart` file

you set,

`home: const CartScreen(),`

and the video tutorial you have followed, he sets `home: ProductListsScreen()`

Fix this and I hope your problem will be solved,

also, be sure where to use `const`

Comment: Setting it to `home: ProductListScreen()` fixed the issue, thanks a lot!